# Magento 2.3.4 - After migration from M1 Category link and filterable attributes takes too much time to load

Tags: category, attributes, migration, magento2.3.4

My `M1` site consists of `30k` products and `100's` attributes.

Attributes like `authors`,`edition`,`publisher` etc.

After successfully migrated to `M 2.3.4` If I click category links and left navigation filterable attributes to take too much time to apply filter.

How to increase the speed of category links and ajax filterable attributes?

Any help thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to improve speed with Website optimisation. Make sure you have merge CSS and JS provide by Magento 2 Feature and also set Production Mode enable.

Comment: After merging CSS and js still category & attributes takes too much time to load. If i click category, it takes 120 seconds takes to display the page.

Comment: have you check and scan your website in google page speed and gtmetrix? Improve score of your website. and make sure you have enable production mode.

Comment: Yes, as a usual report, all my pages working well except the main category and filterable attributes.